# ruby: method_missing backtick typo?

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror, mutt, method-missing

I was building a method to send me an email through mutt when my ruby scripts fail.  It looks something like this:

```
begin
    UnknownFunction()
rescue
    subject = 'Error'
    to_array = ['email@email.com','email2@email.com']
    body = "An error occurred:\n#{$!}"
    %x[echo "#{body}" | mutt -s "#{subject}" #{to_array.join(",")}]
end
```

the command was throwing the following error:

```
sh: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
sh: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I finally looked closely enough to see that $! contains a backtick before the undefined method's name followed by a single quote:

```
undefined method `UnknownFunction' for main:Object
```

I dug into the code and verified the method_missing method has a backtick before and single quote afterwards.  Should the backtick be a single quote or vice versa?  If not, what's the reasoning behind it?

```
raise NoMethodError, "undefined method `#{mid}' for #{self}", caller(1)
```

Comment: I have noticed that before, it's always messing up my inline code on SO when pasting errors since it includes one or more backticks. I have no idea what the reasoning can possibly be.

Comment: are the double quotes not supposed to be like this -> mutt -s "#{subject} #{to_array.join(",")}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a substitute for an open single quote (‘) in plain text/pre-Unicode environments. See: [Why do plain-text technical articles often enclose terms within backticks and single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432952/why-does-html-markup-often-enclose-text-with-backticks-and-single-quotes)

Comment: Interesting, but it looks ridiculous to mix a backtick with a regular single quote. Very surprising this caught on.

Comment: In that situation, the backtick is visually similar to a left-curly-single quote character, just as the regular single-quote is its matching counterpart, and is why they use them. TTYs didn't have curly quotes. Not everything we see in programming and OSes is modern; A lot of it harkens back 40 years or more.

Answer (score 2):

The description of the NoMethodError is not meant to be code, so the use of a backtick there is purely for aesthetic reasons. If you want to pass an arbitrary string to the shell, use [Shellwords.shellescape](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape).

Comment: my solution was to gsub any backticks to single quotes.  the script isn't sophisticated nor elegant, I just need it to get the job done.

Comment: @dukebd711: I can't imagine why, since there's really no benefit to doing it with gsub versus properly shell escaping — but hey, it's not my code, so I'm glad you found something that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

backticks are fine for simple commands, but once you start throwing data at the child process I think its better to use something more sophisticated than piping the text via `echo`. I'd use [`IO.popen`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-popen):

```
IO.popen(
  "mutt -s '%s' %s" % [ subject, to_array.join(',') ],
  'w'
) do |mutt|
  mutt.puts body
end
```

That's untested but is what I'd start with. It's more readable because it gets rid of the backtick jungle of interpolated variables. It also avoids potential problems of the sub-shell trying to help by interpreting variables or looking for embedded backticks in the text being sent to mutt.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, I would definitely recommend shell-escaping the string properly rather than writing a potentially broken shell escape with `tr`. What if another exception that hasn't been encountered yet contains another character that makes the command barf?

Comment: that's true. `Shellwords::shellescape` is more thorough, *and* it's a wheel that doesn't need to be reinvented.